# @Before is not instancing my object for @Test then

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, compiler-errors

I'm actually instancing the object `Persona` at my `@Before`, but at the test, eclipse tells me that `"p cannot be resolved"`.

```
public class PersonaTest {

    // With next line here, app is working, but im trying to understand the 
    // @Before

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.setDni(38890422);
        p.setEdad(24);
        p.setNombre("Nicolas");
        p.setSueldo(25000);
    }


    @Test
    public void testGestDni() {
        int resultado = p.getDni();
        int resultadoEsperado = 38890422;

        Assert.assertEquals(resultadoEsperado, resultado);
    }
}
```

I can make it work, if I instance the object at class. But I want to make the `@Before` work.

Comment: Local variables are... local. A variable declared in a method can only be used in that method. That has nothing to do with JUnit. So if you want p to be accessible in both methods, it needs to be a field, not a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is a local variable in your `setUp` method. If you want it to be accessible to other methods, you should make it a member variable:

```
public class PersonaTest {
    private Persona p; // changed to a member

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // But p is still initialized here:
        p = new Persona();
        p.setDni(38890422);
        p.setEdad(24);
        p.setNombre("Nicolas");
        p.setSueldo(25000);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGestDni() {
        int resultado = p.getDni(); // Tests can now use p
        int resultadoEsperado = 38890422;

        Assert.assertEquals(resultadoEsperado, resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice nice, im understanding, and there is any diff between that way you did and making the entire line "Persona p = new Persona();" in the class directly?

Comment: @Nezvi yes - you're still relying on JUnit's mechanism to run a `@Before` method before each test (which is the right way to use JUnit, like you attempted to do in your original post)

Answer (score 1):

To insure that the Persona instance variable p gets constructed insid the "setUp" - put " p= new Persona(); " inside the setUp method.
Change the declaration of the instance to simply " Persona p; " (without the "new..." there)
That way, the object gets created within the setup method before each test gets called.

The declaration of "Persona p; " must still be there outside of the @Before/setup method. If the declaration is inside that method (along with the "new" call) it only is available *within* the setup method. You need it to be available to the test methods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to import the file where you define what a "Persona" object is. Otherwise, your test file would have no way of knowing, which is why it throws the error saying that "p cannot be resolved."

At the top of this test file try including a statement like:

```
import <package_name>.Persona
```

Comment: Im already importing the class, i didnt pasted it at the code here. (my bad).

Comment: then I believe you should create Persona p inside your setup method, otherwise the internal method will have no way of knowing what p is.